# SubTotal - unable to get the correct value for the fields where avg out the vlaue

Tags: spotfire

I need your help on the below two points:

1) When I subtotal the value based on the allocation key, the fields where i have used avg() to sum up the percentage is not summing up correctly.
2) How can i provide the different color coding for the sub total row and the header in the report.

Please refer the snippet for your easy reference.

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CdAZ.jpg)

Coding:-
Avg(If([Qtr]="Q1",[percentage])) as [Q1 %], 
Sum(If([Qtr]="Q1",[Total  Value $])) as [Q1],

Avg(If([Qtr]="Q2",[percentage])) as [Q2 %], 
Sum(If([Qtr]="Q2",[Total  Value $])) as [Q2],

Answer (score 1):

1. There has been an update since 7.11 to allow the user to toggle between calculating values on the underlying data or whats shown in the cell values of the pivot table.

> It is now possible to configure the cross table to calculate subtotals
>   and grand totals based on the aggregated values visualized in the
>   table, as an option to calculating it using the underlying row level
>   data. This is useful, for example, when you want to visualize the sum
>   of the absolute values of the categories displayed in the table:

[image]

2. As far as I know, you cannot do color customization to the Sub or Grand Total rows. You can edit the appearance of the Header row by View > Visual Theme > Edit Custom Theme and modifying the Details Tab. You can also pull in a template from one of the Spotfire Sample Reports that already do it if you want.

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/whats-new-tibco-spotfire?

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications my friends

Comment: If either of these helped you, please up vote/accept as answer. That way in the future, other users will know what works!

Answer (score 0):

The 6.5.3 User's Guide says this regarding the first question:

> Note: The aggregated value for subtotals is not calculated on the
>   values shown in the cross table, but on the underlying row values. For
>   example, if "Average" is used as aggregation measure, the subtotal
>   average of a column is calculated on the rows the column is based on
>   and not on the values shown in the cross table.

I believe that "subtotal average" means the average of the rows involved in the calculation. I don't see any way to customize the way that subtotals are calculated.

For your second question, I don't believe that there's a way to do that, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications my friends